# Applying medianBlur as well as Laplacian and threshold filters

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

I have a function, with the following signature:

```
Mat cartoonifyImage( Mat, Mat );
```

I also have a **VS2010** program as follows, where I apply to a *webcam stream* a number of *filters*, as taught in this book: [Mastering OpenCV](http://www.packtpub.com/cool-projects-with-opencv/book)

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{

  VideoCapture camera;
  camera.open(0);

  if( !camera.isOpened() )
  {
    cerr << "Could not access the camera!" << endl;
    return  1;
  }

  while( true )
  {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    camera >> cameraFrame;

    if( cameraFrame.empty() )
    {
      cerr << "Could not grab a camera frame!" << endl;
      return  1;
    }

    // imshow( "Camera Test", cameraFrame );

    Mat displayedFrame( cameraFrame.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    cartoonifyImage( cameraFrame, displayedFrame );

    imshow( "Cartoonifier!", displayedFrame );

    int keypress = waitKey( 20 );
    if( keypress == 27 ) break;
  }

}
```

Here is my function definition:

```
Mat cartoonifyImage( Mat srcColor, Mat mask )
{
  Mat gray, edges;

  cvtColor( srcColor, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  const int MEDIAN_BLUR_FILTER_SIZE = 7;
  const int LAPLACIAN_FILTER_SIZE = 5;
  const int EDGES_THRESHOLD = 80;

  medianBlur( gray, gray, MEDIAN_BLUR_FILTER_SIZE );
  Laplacian( gray, edges, CV_8U, LAPLACIAN_FILTER_SIZE );
  threshold( edges, mask, EDGES_THRESHOLD, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV );

  return( mask );
}
```

When I run the program, I get a blank (gray) window.
Where the first `imshow` is commented out, I made sure the webcam is working and I can see my own image in the window, so the problem must be elsewhere.
Can anyone help me understand where the problem is and what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: I guess the problem is, that "mask" is reallocated in the function. normally you could do it that way, but you must make sure that  mask has correct type and size already when you give it to your function. the other possibilities are to pass it as a reference parameter or to use your return parameter when you call the function ;)

Comment: hint why `mask` is reallocated in the function: you create it as a `CV_8UC3` but in your function, it becomes the threshold of a single channel image, so it's only `CV_8UC1`

Comment: Micka, no, you don't have to allocate OutputArray vars at all. the missing reference is the problem

Comment: @berak: he doesn't HAVE to allocate it, but if he doesn't he can't use the old array address (in the old header), so IF he does allocate the correct Mat size and type in the beginning, he doesn't HAVE to use reference variables. So he COULD do it that way, but if it's intended he does it wrong because of wrong initialized allocation. So as I said there are at least three different ways to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your displayedFrame never got filled.

(you pass it into the func, it gets manipulated there, but since you gave it a copy, you don't get the result back)

either return a Mat from cartoonifyImage:

```
Mat displayed = cartoonifyImage( cameraFrame );
```

or pass references :

```
void cartoonifyImage( const Mat & cameraFrame, Mat & displayedFrame );
```

Comment: I used your suggestion to pass reference, and it worked, so thank you, but I didn't change the return type to void, because it still returns a series of images; i.e. matrices. Am I correct?

Comment: yea, ok. the 'void' above was more to amplify the different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat cartoonifyImage( Mat srcColor )
{
    Mat gray, edges, mask;

    cvtColor( srcColor, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    const int MEDIAN_BLUR_FILTER_SIZE = 7;
    const int LAPLACIAN_FILTER_SIZE = 5;
    const int EDGES_THRESHOLD = 80;

    medianBlur( gray, gray, MEDIAN_BLUR_FILTER_SIZE );
    Laplacian( gray, edges, CV_8U, LAPLACIAN_FILTER_SIZE );
    threshold( edges, mask, EDGES_THRESHOLD, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV );

    return ( mask );
}

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{

    VideoCapture camera;
    camera.open(0);

    if( !camera.isOpened() )
    {
        cerr << "Could not access the camera!" << endl;
        return  1;
    }

    while( true )
    {
        Mat cameraFrame;
        camera >> cameraFrame;

        if( cameraFrame.empty() )
        {
            cerr << "Could not grab a camera frame!" << endl;
            return  1;
        }

        //imshow( "Camera Test", cameraFrame );

        Mat displayedFrame( cameraFrame.size(), CV_8UC3 );

        displayedFrame = cartoonifyImage(cameraFrame);

        imshow( "Cartoonifier!", displayedFrame );

        int keypress = waitKey( 20 );
        if( keypress == 27 ) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: remark: allocation of Mat array `( cameraFrame.size(), CV_8UC3)` is obsolete in this approach since it gets replaced by a CV_8UC1 image as far as I see.